# I couldn't get average, largest and smallest value from text file

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, file

Why couldn't I calculate all the integer value in my score.txt file to get the average, smallest and largest result printed on to the console correctly?

Task is to store each record(name and score) in an array and able to process the array of the objects to determine:

- The average of all scores
- The largest score and
- The smallest score

my score.txt file :

```
name:   score:
James   10
Peter   40
Chris   20
Mark    24
Jess    44
Carter  56
John    21
Chia    88
Stewart 94
Stella  77
```

My Source code:

```
public class Q2 
{
    private String name = "";
    private int point = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt user for input file name 
        System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
        String findFile = keyboard.next();

        //invoke readString static method 
        readFile(findFile);

        //output the file's content
        System.out.println(readFile(findFile));


    }//end of main



    public static String readFile(String file)
    {
        String text = " ";

        try 
        {
            Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File (file));
            ArrayList<Q2> list = new ArrayList<Q2>(); 
            String name = "";
            int score = 0;
            int count =0; 


            while(scanFile.hasNext())
            {
                 name = scanFile.next();

                 while(scanFile.hasNextInt())
                 {
                     score = scanFile.nextInt();
                     count++;

                 }

                 Q2 data = new Q2(name, score);
                    list.add(data);


            }
            scanFile.close();

            for(Q2 on : list)
            {
                on.calAverage();
                on.smallAndLarge();
                System.out.println(on.toString());
            }


        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return text;

    }//end of readFile 

    /**
     *  Default constructor for
     *  Score class
     */
    public Q2()
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.point = 0;
    }

    public Q2(String name, int point)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.point = point;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public int getPoint() {
        return point;
    }



    public void setPoint(int point) {
        this.point = point;
    }



    /**
     * This calAverage void method is
     * to compute the average of 
     * total point value
     */
    public void calAverage()
    {
        double average = 0.0;
        int sum = 0;

        //compute the sum of point
            sum += getPoint();


        //compute the average of sum 
        average = sum / 10;
        System.out.println("The Average score is " + average );


    }//end of calAverage method 

    public void smallAndLarge()
    {
        int smallest = 0;
        int largest =0;

        smallest = point;
        for(int index = 2; index < 11; index++)
        {
            if(point > largest)
                largest = point;
            if(point < smallest)
                smallest = point;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest num is :" + largest);
        System.out.println("The Smallest num is : " + smallest);
    }


      public String toString() 
      {
            return String.format("\n%s %d\n", getName(), getPoint());
       }


}
```

The output I got when invoked:

```
Enter file name: 
scores.txt
The Average score is 1.0
The largest num is :10
The Smallest num is : 10

James 10

The Average score is 4.0
The largest num is :40
The Smallest num is : 40

Peter 40

The Average score is 2.0
The largest num is :20
The Smallest num is : 20

...etc...
```

What I want my program to output to:

```
The Average score is 47.4
The largest num is : 94
The Smallest num is : 10
```

Comment: You are calculating average small and large per each record of the file. You should read the contents to a list, and then calculate values from the whole list not on each Q2

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array `int[]` scores, you can the [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) class and its methods to calculate avg, min and max of the array like below:

```
int[] scores = { 10, 40, 20, 24, 44, 56, 21, 88, 94, 77 };
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(scores).summaryStatistics();
System.out.println(stats.getAverage()); //<-- 47.4
System.out.println(stats.getMin()); //<-- 10
System.out.println(stats.getMax()); //<-- 94
```

Comment: I suspect OP also wants to know who had the min and max score. Otherwise, this is clearly the way to go.

Comment: @Magnilex Hello, this is possible but in his last output there is no name associated to the min and max scores and at the beginning of the post he speaks about  avg, min and max of all scores without talking about names of the owners.

Comment: hey dariosicily, do you think there’s a method whereby i don’t have to manually key in those integer value ? :)

Comment: @applePine Hello, if you want to keep things simple without streams, you can create a `new int[] scores = new int[list.size()]` and with a loop over your list put the scores[i] element equals to your list element `getPoint()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 collection framework:

```java
public static void printResult(List<Q2> list)
{
    IntSummaryStatistics summarizedStats = list.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Q2::getPoint));

    System.out.println("The Average score is " + summarizedStats.getAverage());
    System.out.println("The largest num is :" + summarizedStats.getMax());
    System.out.println("The Smallest num is : " + summarizedStats.getMin());
}
```

Comment: how do i parse all those records and stats from text file to csv file ?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about score.txt file. You can refer implementation at [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146952/converting-a-text-file-to-a-csv-file).